# Can't catch ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I can't seem to catch constraint violation Exception though I see it in the logs.

Entity

```
@Column(unique = true)
private String email;
```

I  am trying to catch it like this

```
try {
        memberDao.create(newMember);
} catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {

    //

}
```

-- it never reaches the catch block.

When I use

catch (Exception e)

I catch "javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction."

Here is the error log:

```
21:24:36,296 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-5) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component MemberDAOImpl for method public abstract void pv243.peaktogether.dao.MemberDAOInt.create(pv243.peaktogether.model.Member): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleEndTransactionException(CMTTxInterceptor.java:115) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:95) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:232) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at pv243.peaktogether.dao.MemberDAOInt$$$view178.create(Unknown Source) [peaktogether-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:111) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at pv243.peaktogether.dao.MemberDAOInt$-682821774$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.create(MemberDAOInt$-682821774$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.java) [peaktogether-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
at pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController.register(RegisterController.java:95)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
at 

com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at pv243.peaktogether.filters.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at pv243.peaktogether.filters.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:20)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1177)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:117)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:92) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 75 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "member_email_key"
  Detail: Key (email)=(email@test.com) already exists.
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1361) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1295) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1481) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:109) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:273)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:93)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:164)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1165)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "member_email_key"
  Detail: Key (email)=(email@test.com) already exists.
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:128) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy99.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2849) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3290) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:80) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:264) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:186) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1081) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:315) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:104) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    ... 84 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "member_email_key"
  Detail: Key (email)=(email@test.com) already exists.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157) [postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar:]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1886) [postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar:]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255) [postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar:]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:555) [postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar:]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417) [postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar:]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:363) [postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar:]
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:493)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor206.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    ... 98 more
```

What am I doing wrong ?

UPDATE>>

My current code is:

```
try {
        memberDao.create(newMember);

} catch (EJBTransactionRolledbackException e) {
    log.info("Exception caught!! "+e.getCausedByException());
    log.info("Exception caught!! "+e.getCause());
    log.info("Exception caught!! "+e.getMessage());

    StackTraceElement[] stack = e.getStackTrace();

    for (int i = 0; i< stack.length; i++) {

        log.info(stack[i].toString());
    }

}
```

And the log is

```
 22:02:57,297 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) Exception caught!! javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
22:02:57,298 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) Exception caught!! javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
22:02:57,298 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) Exception caught!! Transaction rolled back
22:02:57,298 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleEndTransactionException(CMTTxInterceptor.java:115)
22:02:57,299 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:95)
22:02:57,299 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:232)
22:02:57,299 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304)
22:02:57,300 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190)
22:02:57,300 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
22:02:57,300 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
22:02:57,301 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
22:02:57,301 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)
22:02:57,301 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
22:02:57,302 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
22:02:57,302 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
22:02:57,302 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32)
22:02:57,303 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
22:02:57,303 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)
22:02:57,303 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
22:02:57,304 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
22:02:57,304 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165)
22:02:57,304 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173)
22:02:57,305 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
22:02:57,305 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
22:02:57,305 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72)
22:02:57,306 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) pv243.peaktogether.dao.MemberDAOInt$$$view241.create(Unknown Source)
22:02:57,306 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
22:02:57,306 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
22:02:57,307 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
22:02:57,307 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
22:02:57,307 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
22:02:57,308 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
22:02:57,308 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
22:02:57,308 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
22:02:57,309 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:111)
22:02:57,309 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
22:02:57,309 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105)
22:02:57,310 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) pv243.peaktogether.dao.MemberDAOInt$-682821774$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.create(MemberDAOInt$-682821774$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.java)
22:02:57,310 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController.register(RegisterController.java:98)
22:02:57,310 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
22:02:57,310 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
22:02:57,311 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
22:02:57,311 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
22:02:57,311 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
22:02:57,312 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
22:02:57,312 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
22:02:57,312 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
22:02:57,313 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
22:02:57,313 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
22:02:57,313 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
22:02:57,313 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
22:02:57,314 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
22:02:57,314 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
22:02:57,314 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
22:02:57,315 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
22:02:57,315 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
22:02:57,315 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
22:02:57,315 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
22:02:57,316 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
22:02:57,316 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
22:02:57,317 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
22:02:57,317 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
22:02:57,317 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) pv243.peaktogether.filters.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:48)
22:02:57,317 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
22:02:57,318 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
22:02:57,318 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) pv243.peaktogether.filters.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:20)
22:02:57,318 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
22:02:57,319 INFO  [pv243.peaktogether.web.controller.RegisterController] (http-
```

Environment:
PostgreSQL 9.2
JBoss AS 7.1.1
JPA 2.0

Cheers,
OSiRiS

Comment: Catch the RollbackException.

Comment: You may never be able to catch it due to wrapping. But.. try flushing the session in the line below `memberDao.create(newMember);` (while still inside the `try` block).

Comment: @acdcjunior Thanks! It's so simple to forget that calling method on entity manager is not the same as running SQL in DB and JPA make calls later :D

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It is wrapped in a `EJBTransactionRolledbackException`, so you should try to catch that one instead of `ConstraintViolationException`.

The `ConstraintViolationException` is first wrapped by a `PersistenceException`, then by a `RollbackException`, and at last by an `EJBTransactionRolledbackException`.

You should call the `getCause()` method of the `Exception` till you encounter the constraint violation or null, which would indicate that the exception is not due to a constraint violation. You can try something like:

```
try {
    memberDao.create(newMember);
} catch (EJBTransactionRolledbackException e) {
    Throwable t = e.getCause();
    while ((t != null) && !(t instanceof ConstraintViolationException)) {
        t = t.getCause();
    }
    if (t instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
        // Here you're sure you have a ConstraintViolationException, you can handle it
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reaseon I can't seem to import EJBTransactionRolledbackException. I have this in pom.xml `<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
  <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>` anyway, I wanted to catch ConstraintViolationException becuase I wanted to call getConstraintName() method on it. Which wont be possible when Ill catch the exception you have suggested

Comment: It's an exception thrown by your application server. You should add the JBoss runtime libraries to your buildpath so that you can use the exceptions (and other classes) used by your server.

Comment: You can get the wrapped exceptions with the `getCause()` method of the `Exception` class. You call it till you find your `ConstraintViolationException`, or null if it's not due to a constraint violation.

Comment: I have updated my first post, please have a look at it and suggest how can I get handle to ConstraintViolationException because nothing in the log really points to it.

Comment: I added to my answer a loop to get the ConstraintViolationException in the catch block.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks this approach is ugly? And apparently there's no way to do it more elegant. I was willing to somehow return the violation message to the users (in a web app), but probably it'll be better for the code quality to just add a validating `if throw` in a proper place than to put so much logic with `instanceof` checks into a catch clause.

Comment: @Scadge All this cruft make me wonder if those who spec'd this out ever even used their own APIs for anything, having to catch and examine like this is truly hideous

Comment: for newer versions of JPA the root wrapper seems to be `EJBException` instead of `EJBTransactionRolledbackException`. And this solution is only for a hoefully rare violation case, so the `instanceof` operations aren't much costly. Please provide suggestions in code if you claim against this

Comment: You can also catch `DataAccessException` without having to import anything extra.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was a stupid reason.

`ConstraintViolationException` that I had in my `Catch` block was imported from `javax.validation` package. Ideally, it should have come from `org.hibernate.exception` package.